# JS - input search returns all objects in array when no value

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I'm looking to make sure that when the input field is empty, no results return. Right now if you type in a name and then delete all your text, you get all the results in the array.

```js
const characters = [{
    first_name: "Abraham",
    last_name: "Lincoln",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Abraham_Lincoln_O-77_matte_collodion_print.jpg"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Johnny",
    last_name: "Bravo",
    img: "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYTg4MDkwODgtYTBlNy00Yjc2LTg4NTYtZGE5YmFhYjY5NzU2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTM3MDMyMDQ@._V1_.jpg"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Barney",
    last_name: "Rubble",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Barney_Rubble.png"
  }
];

let searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);

function filterNames() {
  let filterValue = document.getElementById('searchInput').value.toUpperCase();
  let output = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    let firstName = characters[i].first_name.toUpperCase();
    if (firstName.indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
      output +=
        '<div class="card">' +
        '<div class="img-container text-center">' +
        '<img src="' + characters[i].img + '" width=180 height=180 />' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="text-center">' +
        '<h5>' + characters[i].first_name + ' ' + characters[i].last_name + '</h5>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML = output
};
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Who are you looking for?" />
</div>

<div id="characters"></div>
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/james_zedd/qkgnpxou/)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: provide your HTML

Comment: Just step through your code one by one. What part of your code has to do with the output (the loop)? When will it output anything, what condition has to be fulfilled (`searchInput` has to be part of `first_name`)? Check the parts of that condition when you have an empty string as "search input" (what is the output of `"foo".indexOf("")`?).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you need to have some code that will empty out your search results.

Adding a simple `if` statement around your code where you empty it out would do the trick:

```
let searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);

function filterNames() {
    let filterValue = document.getElementById('searchInput').value.toUpperCase();
    let output = '';

    if (filterValue) {
      for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
          let firstName = characters[i].first_name.toUpperCase();

          if (firstName.indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
              output +=
                  '<div class="card">' +
                  '<div class="img-container text-center">' +
                  '<img src="' + characters[i].img + '" width=180 height=180 />' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<div class="text-center">' +
                  '<h5>' + characters[i].first_name + ' ' + characters[i].last_name + '</h5>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '</div>';
          }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML = output
};
```

Since you default your `output` to an empty string, if you don't have a `filterValue`, then that empty string will be put as your output, clearing your search results.

Comment: _"then that empty string will be put as your output, clearing your search results"_ - That would be the expected result but in case of an empty `searchInput` every item from `characters` is shown.

Comment: It shouldn't with the addition of the `if (filterValue)` I added. The difference is without it, then empty string is always going to be found in any other string, so you'll get all results. With the `if` statement, you won't go into your `for` loop, so you'll bypass the whole thing.

Comment: _"then empty string is always going to be found in any other string"_ That should be the first part of your answer. Explaining to the TO why his/her script doesn't work as expected and only then give a working solution. :)

Comment: I prefer the other way around. Show working code, then explain why the code works is often easier for people to understand.

Comment: But I don't see any explanation why it doesn't work in your answer. And the first sentence is completely wrong as there is already code to "empty out" the search results but because of the "bug" there will always be a result when `searchInput` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a validation based on:

```
filterValue != ""
```

and if true you change the search

if false you clean the content

Hope this helps :)

```js
const characters = [{
    first_name: "Abraham",
    last_name: "Lincoln",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Abraham_Lincoln_O-77_matte_collodion_print.jpg"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Johnny",
    last_name: "Bravo",
    img: "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYTg4MDkwODgtYTBlNy00Yjc2LTg4NTYtZGE5YmFhYjY5NzU2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTM3MDMyMDQ@._V1_.jpg"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Barney",
    last_name: "Rubble",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Barney_Rubble.png"
  }
];

let searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);

function filterNames() {
  let filterValue = document.getElementById('searchInput').value.toUpperCase();
  let output = '';

  if (filterValue != "") {
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
      let firstName = characters[i].first_name.toUpperCase();
      if (firstName.indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
        output +=
          '<div class="card">' +
          '<div class="img-container text-center">' +
          '<img src="' + characters[i].img + '" width=180 height=180 />' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="text-center">' +
          '<h5>' + characters[i].first_name + ' ' + characters[i].last_name + '</h5>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML = output
  } else {
    document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML = "";
  }

};
```

```css
input {width:50%;margin-bottom:12px;}
.card {display:inline-block;margin-right:12px;float:left;}
.img-container {border:1px solid #000000;}
.text-center {text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Who are you looking for?"/>
</div>

<div id="characters"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not removing inner HTML in case of nothing is typed or when everything is remove.

What you need is, just add

```
if(filterValue ==""){
    document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML  = ""
 }
```

at the end of your code and this should work

Comment: TO is... -> `let output = ''; ... document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML = output`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
if (firstName.indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
```

`.indexOf()` returns `0` when you search for an empty string (`""`). Therefor the condition in the `if` will always be true and the output will show all entries of the `characters` array.

You have to add a "guard" to only enter the `for` loop in case `filterValue` is not empty (an empty string).

```
if (filterValue.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

```js
const characters = [{
    first_name: "Abraham",
    last_name: "Lincoln",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Abraham_Lincoln_O-77_matte_collodion_print.jpg"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Johnny",
    last_name: "Bravo",
    img: "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYTg4MDkwODgtYTBlNy00Yjc2LTg4NTYtZGE5YmFhYjY5NzU2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTM3MDMyMDQ@._V1_.jpg"
  },
  {
    first_name: "Barney",
    last_name: "Rubble",
    img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/Barney_Rubble.png"
  }
];

let searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', filterNames);

function filterNames() {
  let filterValue = document.getElementById('searchInput').value.toUpperCase();
  let output = '';

  if (filterValue.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
      let firstName = characters[i].first_name.toUpperCase();
      if (firstName.indexOf(filterValue) > -1) {
        output +=
          '<div class="card">' +
          '<div class="img-container text-center">' +
          '<img src="' + characters[i].img + '" width=180 height=180 />' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="text-center">' +
          '<h5>' + characters[i].first_name + ' ' + characters[i].last_name + '</h5>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('characters').innerHTML = output
};
```

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Who are you looking for?" />
</div>

<div id="characters"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks so much!